# Windows 8.1 unable to install .NET Framework 3.5 0*800F0906

Tags: .net, windows, windows-8, .net-3.5, windows-8.1

After trying to install .net 3.5 via the program and features (see below).   I was getting unable to install error 800F0906

I am using windows 8.1.

[image: windows features]

Answer (score 5):

I inserted windows 8.1 dvd and mounted to d drive then executed from powershell.

1. Open admin command prompt
2. Type powershell
3. From ps prompt type

Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 'NetFx3' -Source 'd:\sources\sxs'

1. It did take 5 minutes to run.

Comment: Has anyone had an experience where this worked and the `cmd` solution didn't? Also they should put this on the MS website & other forums, even if it's identical to the `cmd` solution (which I don't know if it is).

Comment: @trysis I just experienced this. No other way would work: Online/Offline installers, the `dism` command. Finally using the powershell variant worked.

Comment: It does not work. Microsoft SSUUCCKKSS. Why is Framework 3.5 not installed by DEFAULT on ALL Windows versions ??? FF UU CC KK

Comment: We developers can find a way to do it but the problem is when we ship applications that need .Net framework 3.5 and the end user installs it on windows 8.1.. so weird from microsoft

Answer (score 4):

See http://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/windows-8-fix-enable-feature-net-3-5-error-0x800f0906/ for a detailed description.

Enter in cmd (run with administratoir rights):
`dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFX3 /All /Source:E:\Sources\SxS /LimitAccess` (e: is your DVD drive)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a GPO that blocks updates directly from Microsoft. Did not check the WSUS server to see if the required packages were present. Simply made these registry changes and the PC was able to pull down the updates. Note, no need to undo these as the GPO will do it for you.

```
----- Below this line is the actual content to create your own .REG file -----

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate]
"DisableWindowsUpdateAccess"=dword:00000000
"DisableWindowsUpdateAccessMode"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I can confirm there are no policies defined in my case yet I get 0x800F0906 error when installing .Net 3.5 framework. Its a clean install of windows 8.1 pro 64 bit

Comment: What does GPO stands for?

Answer (score 1):

> Found link that identifies two Windows Updates as the problem if DISM
>   and the offline installer do not work.  Uninstall  KB2966826 and
>   KB2966828, then try installing 3.5 from programs and features.  It
>   worked for me.

[By Chris Wardario](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-winapps/cant-enable-or-install-net-framework-35-in-windows/2f221b25-8d17-421f-8c37-1fed61649b4f)

Comment: You copied that link. But you did not try it. This problem has nothing to do with a KB. It even happens on a completely fresh Windows without any KB being installed.

Comment: I have just installed a clean windows 8.1 pro 64 bit. there are no updates whatsoever and yet I get the same error. This appears to be a problem on the update server of MS

Answer (score 0):

I had to log in as a local admin account, rather than runas to get it to download the missing binaries.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily set User Account Control (UAC) to Never notify.

Start -> Control Panel

Search for uac and select Change User Account Control settings

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today and it ended up being a problem with the WSUS server not having the necessary updates synced. To test this, I removed the PC from the policy that points the the WSUS server and adding the feature through the control panel is now working. I don't know if this will apply to everyone but I figured I would add my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue.

**Cause:**
under gpeditor, MS update service location was set to some local WSUS.

**Solution:**
copy that URL and set MS update service location disable or Not configured from gpeditor.
now try steps from feature on/off Windows to install .Net Framework 3.5.
after successfully completion revert WSUS update service URL.

[**for MS update service location:**
under Run=> gpedit.msc
navigate to Comp Conf->Admin Templates->Win Components->Win Update->"Specify internet MS update service location"
]

if MS update service location is not configured then check internet connection otherwise it's some other related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has some changes...

Try the full pack [Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service pack 1 (Full Package)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25150)

Answer (score -1):

check your windows firewall. That must be turned on.