# Windows 8.1 Unable to Install SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, windows-8.1

I am trying to install SQL Server on a VM of Windows 8(.1). I installed it before, but then I deleted the VM and created an identical copy. Now, I can't seem to install it at all. This was all on a Windows 8.1 host, with a Windows 8 guest from my school (seems to be a Developer or preview edition). I forget my process the 1st time, but this was my process this time:

1. Install Guest Additions, then update with Windows Update, then update to Windows 8.1 from the Windows Store, then more updating from Windows Update.
2. Install Visual Studio 2013. I'm not sure if this matters, but given how incompatible MS products are with each other, I'm putting it here.
3. Attempt to install SQL Server 2012, failing every time, right at the very end.
4. Troubleshoot SQL Server installation. It gets cryptic errors, which I look up. They seem to have to do with .NET 3.5 not being installed, so I go to Programs & Features and attempt to enable `.NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0)`, the first "feature" in the list. This fails.
5. Troubleshoot enabling .NET 3.5. The error seems to be that I can't connect to the Internet, but I am connected to the Internet, and can go to several pages in Google Chrome from both guest & host. I try different networks, I try turning off Avast! (host) and Windows Firewall (guest), but still nothing, so I give up and try something else.
6. Troubleshoot enabling .NET 3.5 more. There is another method on the bottom of the MS support page, saying to enter the command `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess`. It installs .NET 3.5 right from the Windows 8 installation media (why this couldn't be done when installing Windows 8, I can't fathom). I try it (`E:` is the drive with the installation disk), but get the error:

   Error: 0x800f081f

   The source files could not be found.
   Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required t
   o restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

   The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
7. Troubleshoot this new error. When I Google the error (`0x800F081F`), it says Windows Update is probably corrupt or something similar and to clean Windows Update by entering the commands `dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`, in that order, but these 2 find nothing wrong, yet when I try the previous command, it still reports errors. Now, I finally give up and come here, to `StackOverflow`.
8. Troubleshoot some more with Stack answers. I try `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 'NetFx3' -Source 'd:\sources\sxs'`, suggested by @bjorn. This fails with the output:

   Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : The source files could not be downloaded.
   Use the "source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more
   information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.
   At line:1 char:1

   - Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName 'NetFx3' -Source 'e:\sources\ ...
   - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

     - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
     - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand

The `cmd` and `PowerShell` commands seem to claim that I didn't specify a source, or at least that I didn't specify a source with the correct files in it, but I used what claims to be a Windows 8 installation media, and did seem to install Windows 8, from my school. Is it possible this CD was an early version without support for the features I'm trying to obtain?

Also, the `Programs and Features` option claimed that I was not on the Internet, or otherwise couldn't establish a connection, but I was on the Internet and successfully visited several sites like Google. It's funny to me that the help article MS directs you to for directions to get on the Internet itself requires the Internet to view, but that's another matter. Is it possible that my VM wasn't set up properly or something to that effect?

**What's happening with my SQL Server 2012**? Is there some incompatibility with Visual Studio 2013? This is on a VM with virtually nothing else on it. Besides the usual settings configuration, it has maybe 3 programs, none of which should have anything to do with these MS products. Also, why was I able to install SQL Server before, on essentially the same VM, yet now I am not?

Comment: Have you tried the answer from David to this question?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188234/windows-8-1-unable-to-install-net-framework-3-5-0800f0906?rq=1

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't work. See my updated post in a couple minutes when I update it.

Comment: remove the updates KB2966826 and KB2966828 before trying to activate .net 3.5

Comment: I think this worked. Do you know why these updates mess up Windows Update or whatever?

Comment: I read this in a forum where an user had the same issue. But they haven't provided the logs, so I don't know why those 2 updates break .net 3.5 setup.

Comment: OK, well, thanks either way. I hope MS fixes those updates with another update soon.

Comment: I asked my contacts at Microsoft and the updates have Metadata issues so tat WU has issues to get the data when you activate .net 3.5. They try to fix this.

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981, that definitely helps.

Comment: were you now able to install SQL Server after activating .net 3.5?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm not sure I want to try updating those 2 again, though.